# Cross-Domain redirect after ajax request

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, custom-headers, easyxdm

i simply need to load a cross-domain asp.net page using jQuery's load() function, but this page can trigger a redirect (i have access to both Server and Client pages).

The loaded page is an asp.net page and i use from server:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.it")
```

but chrome cancels the redirect request. I already googled a lot about this and lot of people say "use CORS", i can't because cors are not supported on IE7 and i need to support that browser.

I tried with Custom Headers but seems like i can't read those from a cross domain, even if the server have this in web.config:

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://10.0.0.158" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
```

Yes, `http://10.0.0.158` is my local "client page" ip.
After some googling i read about [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) libraries but i'm still not sure they can do the trick. Can i use those? How? Have i other alternatives?

Ps: i get the header with this:

```
jQuery('body').bind('ajaxSuccess',function(event,request,settings){
                console.log("ajaxSuccess triggered: "+request.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
```

and it writes only this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
```

with fiddler the header is a lot bigger with all my custom headers.